# Iterate Ma For Each Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft

I have a LinkedHashMap and it has a value (checked on the debugger) but when I tried to use it as input for for each component, it throwing this error :

```
"Expecting Array or Object but got Null. evaluating expression "payload. entrySet()"
```

Here is my snippet for the for each :

```
<foreach collection="#[payload.entrySet()]">
...
</foreach>
```

Pretty sure that the payload is not null and empty and is instance of HashMap. Did I missed something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Foreach iterates over elements of an iterable connection or stream. I don't think a map qualifies for that. To understand the error it is better to use DataWeave terminology instead of Java terminology or concrete types, like the types that you see in the debugger. A Java map is an object and a list is an array. You tried to use a Java instance method from a map implementation (LinkedHashMap) but that will not work (see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-java-methods for what would work, but doesn't apply to this problem). Instead, thinking on DataWeave terms, you can use the function [entriesOf()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-entriesof) to get an array of entries that you can iterate over with foreach:

```
#[entriesOf(payload)]
```